# Solidity Inheritance - when is parent function invoked?

Tags: solidity

I have 2 contracts:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;


contract Bar {
    uint public b;
    address  owner;

    constructor() public {
        b = 100;

    }

}

contract Thing is Bar {
    uint public foo;
    constructor() public {
        foo = 1;
    }

    function setFoo(uint x) public {
        foo = x;
    }

}
```

On remix, I notice that when I deploy `Thing`, its `b` field is set to 100. This means that the parent class is invoked at some point - this seems counter-intuitive.

In most programming languages, you have to explicitly invoke `super` to invoke the parent class; it allows for better flexibility as you have control over *when* you want to invoked the parent functions - something that seems impossible in solidity.

I would love some pointers to understand the inheritance model in solidity.

Comment: `In most programming languages, you have to explicitly invoke super to invoke the parent class` - not in the case of the default constructor. It's true only if the parent constructor takes input arguments, in which case, you have no choice but using it explicitly (either by class name, or by `super`).

Comment: Other than that, the inheritance model is the same as in other OO languages. The implementation behind the scenes is not via V-Table (virtual functions table), but that's not something that you should be bothered with.

Comment: BTW, in `contract Thing`, you can extend `constructor() public` to `constructor() Bar() public` if it really bothers you that the call to the base-class constructor is not explicitly stated in the code.

Comment: BTW2, you should start accepting answers to your question after validating them. That's how this website works.